# Replacing self built Naturals with GHC type level literals

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation, type-kinds

I wrote some code that takes a Heterogeneous List and indexes it.

```
{-# Language GADTs, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses, KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Natural a where
  Zero :: Natural 'Z
  Succ :: Natural a -> Natural ('S a)

data HList a where
  EmptyList :: HList '[]
  Cons :: a -> HList b -> HList (a ': b)

class IndexType (n :: Nat) (a :: [Type]) (b :: Type) | n a -> b where
  index :: (Natural n) -> (HList a) -> b

instance IndexType 'Z (a ': b) a where
  index _ (Cons a _) = a

instance IndexType a b c => IndexType ('S a) (d ': b) c where
  index (Succ a) (Cons _ b) = index a b
```

To do this I implemented my own `Nat` and `Natural` types.  The `Nat` exists solely to elevate to the Kind level and `Natural` exists to fulfill the kind `Nat -> Type`.

Now I would prefer to use `GHC.TypeLits`' `Nat` kind rather than my own however when I try to translate my code over I start to hit a wall in terms of understanding.

I want to build my `IndexType` class and the declaration line doesn't change any

```
class IndexType (n :: Nat) (a :: [Type]) (b :: Type) | n a -> b where
```

Since `GHC.TypeLits` also has its own `Nat` kind.  However `GHC.TypeLits` doesn't have a replacement for `Natural` that I see, namely I lack something of the kind `Nat -> Type`.  Now I could build an equivalent

```
data Natural a = Natural
```

But this is essentially equivalent the `Proxy` type so I could just use that instead.

```
{-# Language GADTs, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses, KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

data HList a where
  EmptyList :: HList '[]
  Cons :: a -> HList b -> HList (a ': b)

class IndexType (n :: Nat) (a :: [Type]) (b :: Type) | n a -> b where
  index :: (Proxy n) -> (HList a) -> b
```

Now the first instance of the `IndexType` class is easy enough:

```
instance IndexType 0 (a ': b) a where
  index _ (Cons a _) = a
```

However the second one starts to puzzle me.  The first line seems as if it would be

```
instance IndexType a b c => IndexType (1 + a) (d ': b) c where
```

However on the second line I don't know how to replace the `Succ` in the original code.  The data constructor for `Proxy` is `Proxy` so I suppose it must use that constructor so I must write something like:

```
  index Proxy (Cons _ b) = index a b
```

But now I'm pulling the definition of `a` out of thin air.  I suppose it has to be another `Proxy` since index takes a `Proxy`, but I don't know how to force it to be the correct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
class IndexType (n :: Nat) (a :: [Type]) (c :: Type) | n a -> c where           
  index ::  (Proxy n) -> (HList a) -> c                                         
instance IndexType 0  (a ': b) a where                                          
  index _ (Cons a _) = a                                                        
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (IndexType (a-1) b c) => IndexType a (d ': b) c where 
  index _ (Cons _ b) = index (Proxy @(a-1)) b
```

This will use some extra extensions including `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications`. PoC (tested on GHC 8.2.2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Foo where
import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

data HList a where
  EmptyList :: HList '[]
  Cons :: a -> HList b -> HList (a ': b)

class IndexType (n :: Nat) (a :: [Type]) (c :: Type) | n a -> c where
  index ::  (Proxy n) -> (HList a) -> c
instance IndexType 0  (a ': b) a where
  index _ (Cons a _) = a
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (IndexType (a-1) b c) => IndexType a (d ': b) c where
  index _ (Cons _ b) = index (Proxy @(a-1)) b

list :: HList '[Int, Bool]
list = Cons (5 :: Int) (Cons True EmptyList)
int :: Int
int = index (Proxy @0) list
bool :: Bool
bool = index (Proxy @1) list
```

Comment: What does the `@` symbol do?  I've only ever seen it used for pattern matching before.

Comment: @WheatWizard The `@` symbol here is a use of the very nice recent feature `TypeApplications` https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications